# tikz decorations to create arrow head (positioning problem)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-decorations

I would like to create my own arrow head (a crossed circle). I try with `decorations.markings` and it works.
However, the decoration enter the pointed node.
I would like that the decoration only touch that node.
Can you help me ?

This is what I get :

[image: What I get]

This is what I want :

[image: What I want]

My code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
    entity/.style = {
        draw,rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm
    },
    -contains/.style = {
        decoration={markings,
                mark=at position 1 with {
                    %\node[draw,circle,fill=white,anchor=south east] (circle) {};
                    \node[draw,circle,fill=white] (circle) {};
                    \draw[-] (circle.north west) -- (circle.south east);
                    \draw[-] (circle.north east) -- (circle.south west);
            }
        },
            postaction={decorate}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[entity] (A) {\textbf{A}};
    \node[entity,below right=1 and 0.5 of A] (B){\textbf{B}};
    \draw[-contains] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `shorten >=10pt`?

Answer (score 1):

If an extra step is OK, you can make a circular node with cross first, and draw the line afterward.

Below I also show an example of creating an actual arrow tip, but this also has problems with positioning, unless the line meets the node at an angle of 90 degrees.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=Contains,
  parameters= {\the\pgfarrowlength},  
  setup code={
   \pgfarrowssettipend{0pt}
   \pgfarrowssetlineend{-\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
   \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code={
   \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{-0.5\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}{0.5\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.85355\pgfarrowlength}{0.35355\pgfarrowlength}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.14644\pgfarrowlength}{-0.35355\pgfarrowlength}}
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-0.14644\pgfarrowlength}{0.35355\pgfarrowlength}}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-0.85355\pgfarrowlength}{-0.35355\pgfarrowlength}}
   \pgfusepathqstroke
  },
  defaults = { length = 7pt }
}
\tikzset{
    entity/.style = {
        draw,rectangle,minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm
    },
    contains/.style={
      draw,circle,fill=white,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=7pt,outer sep=0pt,
      path picture={
         \draw (path picture bounding box.north west) -- (path picture bounding box.south east);
         \draw (path picture bounding box.north east) -- (path picture bounding box.south west);
            }
        },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[entity] (A) {\textbf{A}};
    \node[entity,right=3cm of A] (A2) {\textbf{A}};
    \node[entity,below right=1 and 0.5 of A] (B){\textbf{B}};
    \node [contains,anchor=south] (c) at (B.145) {};
    \draw (A) -- (c);
    \draw [->,>=Contains] (A2) -- (B);
    \draw [->,>=Contains,blue] (A2) to[out=180,in=90] (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```